# Need a kind of sampler/tracker

Tags: android, music-production, music-composing

I'd like to experiment with music and sound - creating new and strange scales, chords and modes. And very interesting in random and quasi-random music. So I need a very special app for Android:

1. It should have sampler functionality
2. It's "load/save" patterns should be in simple, read/write format: XML, CSV etc. In order for me to generate them programmatically with my own app.

I tested a lot of apps (FL4A, PocketBand, Sunvox, Caustic etc) and all of them load/save patterns in some encoded, binary format.

ChordBot is a great app and it uses XML-like songs. But it has no sampler functionality at all...

I'll be grateful for any info!

Comment: Not working in that area, but you're welcome to check my list of apps for [Audio Editing](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_music_audioedit#group_863). Raw guess: [Walk Band](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.gamestar.pianoperfect) *might* fit.

Comment: Great collection, thanx! And WB is very good (and cheap), but has no sampler

Comment: Sorry for the wrong pick then. If one of the others fulfills your requirements, be welcome to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) :)